# Linking Intel's MKL (BLAS & LAPACK) to GCC

Tags: c++, linker, lapack, blas, intel-mkl

I am trying to compile a giant software package, and this is the last hurdle I can't seem to figure out.

I'm getting errors like:

```
RNDiracDeterminantBase.cpp:(.text+0x22bf): undefined reference to `dgetrf_'
RNDiracDeterminantBase.cpp:(.text+0x2524): undefined reference to `dgetri_'
RNDiracDeterminantBase.cpp:(.text+0x3005): undefined reference to `dgetri_'
../../lib/libqmcwfs.a(RNDiracDeterminantBase.cpp.o): In function `qmcplusplus::RNDiracDeterminantBase::ratio(qmcplusplus::ParticleSet&, int, qmcplusplus::ParticleAttrib<qmcplusplus::TinyVector<double, 3u> >&, qmcplusplus::ParticleAttrib<double>&)':
RNDiracDeterminantBase.cpp:(.text+0x4156): undefined reference to `dgemv_'
RNDiracDeterminantBase.cpp:(.text+0x420f): undefined reference to `dger_'
```

Google reveals that these references are to Intel's MKL library.  However, I don't know what file I need to link.  I've tried libmkl_core.a, libmkl_gnu_thread.a, libmkl_blacs_intelmpi_lp64.a, etc.  There's tons of files in:

/mkl/lib/intel64/

Can post more information if requested.

Comment: Please don't *advertise* in your questions.

Comment: Will then can you help me get my question answered?

Comment: Since you seem to have disappeared, I'm changing the title back.  Feel free to re-edit if you come back.

Comment: Please don't advertise in your questions.

Comment: What about just mentioning *within* the question that I will give a bounty?  That's not advertising since SO does that itself for questions over 2 days old.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advertising

Comment: Yes, but the fact of the matter is, there is no bounty on it currently, and advertising it in the title is disingenuous.  It's also distracting and it messes with SO's automated systems for giving you similar questions.  It's also rude to other people who are also trying to get their question answered.

Comment: Since you have edit capability, is there someway I can go ahead and put a bounty on it?  I will actually put forth my whole reputation (knowing the answer is worth that).

Comment: This is probably enough to get you the answer you need: http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-mkl-link-line-advisor and I cannot place a bounty on your question using your reputation.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27980/discussion-between-omnipotententity-and-nick)

Answer (score 10):

> I don't know what file I need to link. I've tried libmkl_core.a, libmkl_gnu_thread.a, libmkl_blacs_intelmpi_lp64.a, etc. There's tons of files in: `/mkl/lib/intel64/`

The fact that there are tons of files doesn't mean you have to try each library in turn.

To find out which library defines the symbols you want, run this command:

```
cd /mkl/lib/intel64
nm -A *.a | egrep '[TWBD] (dger_|dgemv_|dgetrf_|dgetri_)$'
```

Also be sure to put libraries at the *end* of your link line, as the order of archive libraries on command line [matters](http://webpages.charter.net/ppluzhnikov/linker.html).

Answer (score 4):

Based on the incomplete information you provided, it's likely that you need libmkl_intel_lp64.a, libmkl_gnu_thread.a, and libmkl_core.a.

Intel MKL has a built-in tool to help you figure out linking: /mkl/tools/mkl_link_tool. This tool is also available on the web: http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-mkl-link-line-advisor. Use this tool to get the exact link line for your situation.

You should have asked your question on the official MKL forum (http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-math-kernel-library). You'd get the answer for this type of questions within hours instead of days.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem when setting up mingw on windows.

The following library linking order worked for me with gcc:

1. mkl_intel_thread
2. mkl_rt
3. mkl_core
4. mkl_intel_lp64

Hope this helps anyone stuck with this problem.